# How to Extract the needed data in this Html using Jsoup

Tags: android, html, jsoup

I am new to Jsoup library. And this piece of HTML is giving me hell parsing iy.

**Remote HTML**

```
//Skipped the meta and header because I don't need it.
...
<body class="sin">
<div class="ks">
    <div class="wrap">

        <div class="content-right-sidebar-wrap">
            <main class="content">

                //A lot of unneeded tags

                <article class="post-1989009 post type-post post" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/CreativeWork">
                    <header class="post-header">
                        <h1 class="post-title" itemprop="headline">Tyh RGB  Marco to habits gtr</h1>
                        <img src="https://ohniee.com/wp-content/uploads/avatars/1/djsy8933e89ufio8389e8-author-img.jpg" class="avatar user-1-avatar avatar-40 photo" width="40" height="40" alt="Profile photo of Johnnie Adams">

                        <div class="entry-meta" style="padding-top:3px; margin-left: 50px">
                        " Written by "<a href="/authors/johnnie"><span class="entry-author" itemprop="author" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Person"><span class="entry-author-name" itemprop="name">Johnnie Adams</span></span></a> <script>
                        document.write(" on April 23rd, 2002 11:28 PM")</script>" on April 23rd, 2002 11:28 PM  .  "<span class="entry-comments-link"><a href="https://johniee.com/2002/04/thalo-in-American-film-industryk.html#comments">1 Comment</a></span>
                        </div>
                    </header>

                    //A lot of unneeded tags

                   ...
```

**This how I am parsing it:**

```
String post_authordate = document.select("div.entry-meta").first().text();
        postAuthorDate.setText(post_authordate);

        Elements img = document.select("img[class=avater]");
        String author_image = img.attr("src");
        postAuthorUrl.setText(author_image);
```

**And this what I'm getting**

- Wriiten by Johnnie Adams. 1 comment
- For the `postAuthorUrl` nothing
  is showing.

**What I want**

- Written by Johnnie Adams on April 23rd, 2002 11:18 PM
- https://ohniee.com/wp-content/uploads/avatars/1/djsy8933e89ufio8389e8-author-img.jpg

---

### My Code

```
private void loadPost() {
        Log.d(TAG, "loadPost called");

        final ProgressBar progressBar;
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_circle);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


        String news_id = getIntent().getStringExtra("PostId");
        Log.d(TAG, "You clicked post id " + news_id);

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(news_id,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        //Log.d("Debug", response.toString());
                        if (progressBar != null) {
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                        parseHtml(response);
                        postData = response;


                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        VolleyLog.d("", "Error: " + error.getMessage());

                        if (progressBar != null) {
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }

                        final  AlertDialog.Builder sthWrongAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(PostDetails.this);
                        sthWrongAlert.setCancelable(false);
                        sthWrongAlert.setMessage(R.string.sth_wrongme_det);
                        sthWrongAlert.setPositiveButton(R.string.alert_retry, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                if (!NetworkCheck.isAvailableAndConnected(PostDetails.this)) {
                                    internetDialog.show();
                                } else {
                                    loadPost();
                                }

                            }
                        });
                        sthWrongAlert.setNegativeButton(R.string.alert_cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                finish();
                            }
                        });
                        sthWrongAlert.show();
                    }
                });

        //Creating requestqueue
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        //Adding request queue
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);


    }

    private void parseHtml(String response) {
        Log.d(TAG, "parsinghtml");
        Document document = Jsoup.parse(response);


        String post_authordate = document.select("div.entry-meta").get(0).text();

        String img = document.select("img.avatar").get(0).attr("src");

        postAuthorDate.setText(post_authordate);

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

*This is how I read & parse the file with html content*

```
public static String readFile(String path, Charset encoding) throws IOException {
    byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path));
    return new String(encoded, encoding);
}

public void jsouptest() throws IOException {
    // there is a file named "sample.html" in the project directory
    String htmlContent = readFile("sample.html", StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    Document doc = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(htmlContent, "");
    Element body = doc.body();

    String entryMetaText = body.select("div.entry-meta").get(0).text();
    String imgLink =  body.select("img.avatar").get(0).attr("src");

    int commentPos = -1;
    if(entryMetaText.contains("AM")){
        commentPos = entryMetaText.indexOf("AM") + 2;
    }
    else if(entryMetaText.contains("PM")){
        commentPos = entryMetaText.indexOf("PM") + 2;
    }
    if(commentPos != -1)
    {
        entryMetaText = entryMetaText.substring(0, commentPos);
    }

    System.out.println(entryMetaText);
    System.out.println(imgLink);
}
```

Output (Edited for the new sample html):

```
" Written by "Johnnie Adams " on April 23rd, 2002 11:28 PM
https://ohniee.com/wp-content/uploads/avatars/1/djsy8933e89ufio8389e8-author-img.jpg
```

*The first line of output strips anything after PM so extra full stop and quotation mark is missing at the end.*

Comment: The 1 comment is dynamic, it can be `no comments`  `20 comments` blah blah. And I just discovered that `on April 23rd, 2002 11:28 PM` is not showing. It's just showing Writen by Johnnie Adams. 1 comment

Comment: @Ozuf I did a test on your test data. The output does include time stamp in my test as shown in the output. Maybe the sample html is different or missing some tag. And to remove the last portion of the data (the comment portion), you will have to find the common pattern here and then remove.

Comment: @Ozuf What is the version of jsoup you are using? I tested with version 1.8.3 (latest as of today). For  timestamp not coming as text part of the selected tag, an older version of jsoup could be culprit, which might have been fixed in recent or newer version.

Comment: I'm using version 1.9.1

Comment: So it seems that latest is 1.9.1. My bad, I think I may have navigated to 1.8.3 page from the browser's history. I will check with newer version.

Comment: Please, Sir have you checked?

Comment: @Ozuf I tested with jsoup version 1.9.1. The results are identical (i.e. I have the timestamp in the output). Maybe html you are trying with is different than the html you have posted here (an extra tag or a missing tag here & there). Have a look into this (try a diff of both the text using some diff tool).

Comment: there are double-quotes in the timestamp and  *written by*. I have updated **Remote HTML** please can you take a look at it and get back to me? Please.

Comment: @Ozuf I have updated the output to reflect the new data. As you can see the output still has time stamp. Maybe the way you are reading the html has something in it. I read the html from a file for testing.

Comment: still didn't work. But this is what I am doing

       private void parseHtml(String response) {
            Document document = Jsoup.parse(response);
       
           String post_authordate = document.select("div.entry-meta").get(0).text();

           postAuthorDate.setText(post_authordate);
     

           String img = document.select("img.avatar").get(0).attr("src");


           
    }

Comment: I have added the sample to read file containing html content.

Comment: Also the html content file contains text between the 2 "..." (excluding ...).

Comment: While I couldn't implement your code because I use volley. I have updated my question with the code. Please, please, can you take a look at it?

Comment: please can you use my code and tell me if it'd working for you? plsssss

Answer (score 1):

Try `img[class~=avatar user-(\d+)-avatar avatar-40 photo]` instead of `img[class=avater]`

---

The date in the html source is 2002. You want 2016?

---

### How to get rid of "Comment 1"

`System.out.println(entryMetaText.replaceAll("\d+ Comment",""));`

<strike>`System.out.println(entryMetaText.substring(0, entryMetaText.length() - 9);)`</strike>

Comment: `user-1-avatar` in `img[class=avatar user-1-avatar avatar-40 photo]` changes. It can be `user-145-avatar` or `user-90-avatar`.

Comment: You can select based on regular expression patterns, see edit. Let me know if that works.

Comment: Sorry, it's a typo

Comment: Also, see [here](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html), for more usage beyond your problem here.